# Center header inside parent

Tags: html, css, margin

I use bootstrap and joomla.

I have a new design that requires my div and h2, to be 1920 pixels wide and have centered text. What i have done is:

```
    .page-header {
    background-color:#3c4547;
    width:1920px;
    top:0px !important;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:0px;
    display:block;
    padding:20px 0px 25px 0px;
    z-index:999;
    left:-385px;
}

.page-header h2 {
    color: @white;
    font-size:36px;
    font-weight:400;
   margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
     text-align: center;
}
```

The wrapper is only 1600 pixels wide or something, thats why i cheat with negative margin.

but it doesnt center the text right on resize - its need to be responsive aswell. Any suggestions?

This is my HTML code and i cannot edit it:

```
<div class="page-header"><h2 itemprop="name">Header text</h2></div>
```

It has a  as parents.

This is basicly what i want and have, but it doesnt center on responsive:
[image]
.
and this is how it looks just with just 100% width:

[image]

For Lion and others, to explain the whole code:

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="page-header>
<h2>testest</h2>
</div>
</div>

.parent {
width:1000px;
}

.page-header {
width:100%;
background:red;
}

.h2 {
color: #ffffff;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the div to be wider then the display?  maybe set it's max-width property to 100% will help

Comment: is this u want? http://jsfiddle.net/dkokkcom/ or something else.. share some picture.

Comment: Try using `position:absolute;` instead of `marign:-385px;`.

Comment: I posted some pictures :-)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/0j1ze4yn/

Comment: @Dmitriy the problem is, 100% width is not enough for me, i need 1920px width, i need it to be full screen size, and the parent is 500 pixels too small or something like that

Comment: @BrittanyMoore  did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guys had some good answers, but didnt really solve my problem - i am sure one of yours can be a solution to another with a problem simular to this, but in my case i solved the problem by using javascript to expand the id tag.

```
if(jQuery('.page-header').length > 0){
    pageHeader = jQuery('.page-header');
    jQuery('#main').prepend(pageHeader);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**
please replace your code to this

```
.page-header {
    background-color:#3c4547;
    width:100%;
    top:0px !important;
    margin-top:0px;
    display:block;
    padding:20px 0px 25px 0px;
    z-index:999;
    left:-385px;
}

.page-header h2 {
    color: @white;
    font-size:36px;
    font-weight:400;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

no need of position..

Sorry if i did not get your point but if you want to make your h2 center align then why don't you use margin..

see this

```
.page-header{width:100%;}
h2{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:auto;text-align:center;}
.section{ margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;text-align: center; width: 100%;}
```

i am assuming that you wanted to make your h2 text center align with responsiveness so i typed code like this..correct me if m wrong..

**For Testing**

```
<div class="page-header">
<h2 itemprop="name">Header text</h2>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <p>lalalala</p>
    <p>lalalala</p>
    <p>lalalala</p>
    <p>lalalala</p>
    <p>lalalala</p>
</div>
```

please check my example and let me know your structure is different.. ty

screenshot
[image: first]

[image: sec]

[image: three]

Comment: and yup i use .page-header{width:1600px;} this also in my code.

Comment: And it centers perfectly, but when i resize it doesnt: http://i.imgur.com/lW4WrGe.png

Comment: yes coz i applied css on h2 only but can you please provide full code so i can tell you..as in example you are talking about p tag so you have to apply same css on p tag..please provide full tag or let me change my code.one sec

Comment: It works well, but it doesnt go 100% of the page width (which i want in this case), because of the parent is as small as it is. I need it to fit 100% of the screen width. Look this:

http://imgur.com/CWJfjdu

Comment: For me its in 100% width..can you please paste your whole code related to test test so i can see what is issue as for me its working well.

Comment: check my ans with screens.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ** try to use this code, i hope this code will help you :)**

div h2 {
    max-width: 1920px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: you need to center your text?

Comment: And it does center, but when i resize it gets like that

Comment: your parent should be max-width, not width :)

Comment: @BrittanyMoore i updated my answer with your code..test that plz